# Refresh contentComponent in react-navigation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am using [React-Navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) where I am using functionality of custom drawer by using `contentComponent` of React-Navigation.

```
const DrawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({
  DrawerStack: { screen: DrawerStack }
}, {
  contentComponent: DrawerComponent,
  drawerWidth: 300
})
```

Here DrawerComponent is my custom navigation drawer where I have used custom navigation items like username, profile picture, email address and other menus.

Now whenever user updates their profile I want to refresh my DrawerComponent, I am not able to find any way to do it. Can anybody suggest me a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

Couple of options here, and all are tight to how you want to achieve your state management.

First, one solution would be to have the your user state in the component creating the `DrawerNavigator`, and pass it down to your custom drawer component. This presents the disadvantage of having to recreate your navigator on state change and create a blink. I do not advice to use this solution but it's worth mentioning as a possibility.

You could also use a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), have your user state in a top level component, create a provider passing it the user as the value and make your drawer a consumer of this context. This way, every time the user changes your drawer component would re-render.

---

What I use personally is Redux to connect my Drawer directly to my global state. It involves a bit of setup but it's worth it in the end. A root component could look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)
```

Where `store` is the result of:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import reducers from './reducers'

const store = createStore(combineReducers(reducers))
```

Your reducers are going to be the state of your app, and one would be dedicated to your user data.

Then your Drawer component could be:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

@connect(({ user }) => ({ user }))
class Drawer extends Component {
  render () {
    const { user } = this.props
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>My name is {user.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Drawer
```

Now, every time you change your user reducer, this Drawer component will re-render.

There is a few things your should know about Redux, so you should probably read up a bit the [Getting Started docs](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started).

Comment: this is one way to do it, another way would be to use event listeners incase you don't prefer using redux.

Comment: This is **3** ways to do it, I never said there was no other ones :)

Comment: you're right, i guess the third way is to use the react context.

Comment: To be precise, I talk about how to do it in 3 different ways in my answer, event listeners is a 4th one.

Comment: you're right again, i gave your answer a quick look, and only saw redux code, so i assumed it only covered the redux way.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a old question now but you can do this by importing the code like

```
import DrawerView from '../Drawer/Drawer'

contentComponent: DrawerView

then in the DrawerView file

class DrawerView extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            //Do your stuff here
        )
    }
}

export default DrawerView;
```

for more info please visit this link and thank to Kakul Gupta for this  https://codeburst.io/custom-drawer-using-react-navigation-80abbab489f7

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change menus without using redux is, using createSwitchNavigator.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: I spend an evening doing it with redux, but couldn't do it, then I read the documentation and found the solution.